# Joomla: Forcibly log user out

Tags: php, session, joomla

**Joomla 1.7.2**: I fear I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be. Here's what I need to do:

```
if( !$this->userInUserGroup() ){
    // Log the user out
    // Redirect to home page displaying system message
    $this->setRedirect( '/', 'You must be in Usergroup XYZ to log in to this website.', 'error' );
    $this->redirect();
}
```

This does not work as I cannot log the user out. `session_destroy()` does not work, as it eliminates the error message data invoked with `$this->setRedirect()`.

I thought about modifying the `login` module, but I'd prefer to not modify the core if I can help it. This method would be comfortably restricted to my `ComponentController` class.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShaneC you can use the mainframe's logout method.

```
global $mainframe;

$mainframe->logout();
```

or

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->logout();
```